# Set Object Property by Reference

Tags: powershell, reference

I have a collection of PSObjects over which I'd like to iterate, setting contituent member's properties. I set up a `for` loop and pass the current object by reference to a function, but do not know how to access the object properties. Example:

```
function create-object {
    $foo = new-object -TypeName PSObject -Prop `
        @{
            "p1" = $null
            "p2" = $null
        }
    $foo
}

$objCol = @()

foreach ($k in (1 .. 3)){$objCol += create-object} 

for ($i=0;$i -le $objCol.Length;$i++) {
    Write-Host "hi"
    reftest ([ref]$objCol[$i])
}

function reftest([ref]$input)
{
    $input.p1.value="property1"
}
$objCol
```

... returns `Property 'p1' cannot be found on this object` --how do I set $object.p1 from a function by reference?

Comment: `$input` is a reserved name, you need to change it with something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reformatted your example, also incorporating the change of `$input` to a different name, `$arg`, as pointed out by Christian.  The following works:

```
function create-object {
    $foo = new-object PSObject -Property @{
        "p1" = $null
        "p2" = $null
    }
    $foo
}

function reftest($arg)
{
    $arg.p1="property1"
}

$objCol = @()

(1..3) | % {$objCol += create-object} 

for ($i=0;$i -lt $objCol.Length;$i++) {
    reftest $objCol[$i]
}

$objCol
```